# CWP Admin Panel CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Error

Tags: php, web-hosting, cwp

After installation cwp on centos 7 successfully , I can not go to the admin panel .
when i wrote my ip in address bar , see this image that means cwp installed but admin panel page get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT .
[image]

this is my open ports

[image]

and when i use curl command for two ports(2030 , 2031), this result return
[image]